# No component factory found for Component - component already added to NgModule

Tags: angular

I am getting this error when trying to open a modal component:

> No component factory found for [ComponentName].
>   Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

The same modal is working elsewhere in the app so it has been added to the `declarations` and `entryComponents` sections of `NgModule`.

Is there anything else this message could mean?

Comment: Can you show relevant code sections?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you use dynamically loaded components like a dialog window. If this is the case, you need to list them in the entryComponents property of @NgModule, for example:

```
  entryComponents: [
    MyDialogComponent
  ]
```

You can see an example here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview